Open new tab in background with javascript angular
iam trying to open in new tab in background with angular, already browsing about this but it seems still doesn't works.
please see the function below :
 openProductInNewTab(productId: number) {
    const url = this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree(['/product', 'detail', productId]));
    
    // Buka tab baru
    const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer');
    
    setTimeout(() => {

    if (newWindow) {
      window.focus(); // Kembali ke tab utama
      }
    }, 500);
  }

here i attached the html code :
<td style="width: 27%; padding-left: 20px" nowrap *ngIf="this.ls.selectedLanguages == 'id'">
<strong (click)="openProductInNewTab(item.id)" class="text-blue">
              {{ item.name }}
            </strong>
          </td>

so the problem is, my browser (edge) is always open the new tab directly and never go back to the main tab. I want to stay focus on main tab and just open the new tab in background tab for the ideal solution. Do you have any alternative solution about this ? Thank you because iam getting stuck.
i have already trying iframe, put the url on variable a, add the windows.blur() but none of these ever work on my local instead.

Sadly, you cannot make opening website in background.

[...] the browser block this kind of JS nav actions to prevent malicious scripts
~ Aguiargabriel1983 from Bubble Forum

I think you can make like opening the same url and change the href property
function newTabInBackground(url: string) {
    window.open(location.href, 'blank');
    location.href = url;
}


thank you, i've already test it but still not focus in the main page
